# Is https://bugreport.apple.com/web/ restricted to developers?

Tags: apple-id

If so, is there any mechanism for the public to report bugs or is that just included in https://www.apple.com/feedback/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you need a developer *account* and be signed into it to use that mechanism.

> #### [About Apple Bug Reporter](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)
>
> Apple Bug Reporter is a web-based tool that developers can use to
> report issues with Apple software and services, request enhancements
> to APIs and tools, and track the status of their feedback. To access
> Apple Bug Reporter, **sign in with the Apple ID associated with your
> developer account.**

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

The general public would use the public facing feedback page https://www.apple.com/feedback